# What are the intellectual property rights around an idea for film?

Tags: intellectual-property

Consider this hypothetical scenario. Person W (for Writer) wrote document X summarizing other documents publicly available; document X is copyrighted and available to the public in exchange for an email signup.

Person M (for Maker) meets the Writer and they both have the idea of adapting document X for film. The Maker works on it on the side for a few years and releases a pilot episode in the public domain with copyright to the Maker and the Writer.

The Maker requests the help of person D (for Director of film) to make the full series. The Director proposes a quote Y with a budget and time involved. At a meeting of all three parties one month after, the Director proposes a storyline Z with three times the budget and time involved. (Also, the Director has taken two other jobs in the meantime.)

The Maker decides to go ahead with the film series without the Director to meet the timescale mentioned in quote Y. The Writer gives the Maker a license to use document X without mentioning exclusivity.

The Director mentions that they have been in conversation with the Writer and they float the idea of continuing to work together without the Maker. The Director tells the Maker, "I thought the point of the project was that I would work with the Writer directly." The Director has already brought one of their contacts on board and also wanted to bring a producer.

What intellectual property rights are relevant here? Specifically:

- does the Maker have a right to the original idea of adapting document X for film?
- do the Director and the Writer have the right to work on storyline Z independently of the Maker?
- having requested both quotes, does the Maker have a right to producing storyline Z?

Please edit as needed if some information is irrelevant. I did not mention countries since my impression is that film rights tend to be world-wide.

Comment: Ideas are not copyrightable. Repeat. Ideas are not copyrightable.

Comment: Ideas can't be protected by copyright, but they might enjoy some protection as *trade secrets* if there's reasonable effort to protect them as such (e.g. NDAs). Regardless of that point this situation seems like a mess because there don't seem to have been clear contracts. That Writer gives Maker a license to adapt X is the clearest part of the story.

Comment: Can you provide an answer, along with suggestions of what Maker should have done to protect the idea?